# onSingleTapConfirmed

Tags: android, countdowntimer

the proble is :
"Syntax error on token "start", Identifier expected after this token"------on the first start.(loadingAnimation.start();

```
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            AnimationDrawable loadingAnimaton;
            loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ImageView.getBackground();

         }loadingAnimation.start();

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();

    return true;
}});
```